# Is there any formatter for JSONL(JSON Lines) files for vs code?

Tags: json, vscode-extensions, formatter

If so, how do I configure it to be default formatter just for jsonl files when I am using prettier as my default code formatter.

I installed this extenstion: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wekex.JsonLint
but still when I do Alt+Shift+F to format the jsonl file, it prompts me saying that no such formatter is installed.
[vs code install formatter prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46nCv.png)

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to format a [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/) file. Every _individual line_ (`\n`) in the file should be a valid JSON value. The moment you format it to add linebreaks, it's no longer JSONL but a broken file. You chould take _one single line_ from your input and then format it with any JSON formatter but not the entire file at once.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I don't think it doesn't make sense to format the jsonl file. Yeah, I can take each line which itself is json; separately and format it in a new file. But what I wanted was, for example, if I had 10 lines in my jsonl file with nested and 10-20 properties in each of the json line, then I wanted every line to be formatted like a separate json when I hit Alt+Shift+F. Currently I am working with jsonl by using word wrap only, unable to format each json object which would be better for readability.